# Ng v still showing older version number after updating to latest angular cli version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have issued the following commands as shown in the picture. I have got a a success message saying that angular cli has been update to 10.0 version.

**But when I run the ng v command I am getting the old version number.**

So did it really update?
What is the issue here?
How to update to latest version globally so that when I generate a new angular project through cli I get the latest version of angular in that project?

[image]

Pls note- I have tried closing the cmd and opeing a new one to check `ng v` . Still the same. I did this entire process two times.

Not working even after `npm cache clean force`

[image]

```
 c:\>cd Users

c:\Users>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.0.1
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/core         10.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.1
@schematics/angular          10.0.1
@schematics/update           0.1000.1
rxjs                         6.5.5


c:\Users>cd ARPAN

c:\Users\ARPAN>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.3
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.3
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.3
@angular/cli                 8.3.3
@schematics/angular          8.3.3
@schematics/update           0.803.3
rxjs                         6.4.0
typescript                   3.5.3


c:\Users\ARPAN>npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
removed 269 packages in 5.006s

c:\Users\ARPAN>npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache):
Content verified: 497 (12436501 bytes)
Index entries: 753
Finished in 0.97s

c:\Users\ARPAN>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
C:\Users\ARPAN\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\ARPAN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@10.0.1 postinstall C:\Users\ARPAN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@10.0.1
added 269 packages from 206 contributors in 30.831s

c:\Users\ARPAN>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.3
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.3
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.3
@angular/cli                 8.3.3
@schematics/angular          8.3.3
@schematics/update           0.803.3
rxjs                         6.4.0
typescript                   3.5.3


c:\Users\ARPAN>
```

I opened `cmd` in `admin` mode, then updated the angular cli there, It got updated successfully, but then when I open cmd again in normal mode it shows the older version.

So I opened `cmd` in a`admin` mode `in my folder` `c:/users>ARPAN` i updated the angular cli version there , but still it shows the same older version. Pls check the logs that i have attached

Comment: I also have this issue. I've installed Angular 13. But it still shows me version 10 and creates new project in version 10. And the suggestions below don't work for me - I don't have package JSON in Users folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally! I am able to solve it.
In admin mode and in root (`C:\Users>`) folder the `angular cli` version was the latest one i.e, `10.0.1`

But when I was navigating to `C:\Users\ARPAN>` the version of `angular cli` was still `8.3.3` .

```
C:\Users\ARPAN>cd..

C:\Users>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.0.1
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/core         10.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.1
@schematics/angular          10.0.1
@schematics/update           0.1000.1
rxjs                         6.5.5


C:\Users>cd ARPAN

C:\Users\ARPAN>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.3
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.3
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.3
@angular/cli                 8.3.3
@schematics/angular          8.3.3
@schematics/update           0.803.3
rxjs                         6.4.0
typescript                   3.5.3
```

I was not able to figure out what was causing the issue. I tried everything available on the internet and stack overflow.I tried `npm cache clean --force` `npm cache verify`. Nothing worked.

**Then I did the following steps-**

Then I looked inside `C:\Users\ARPAN>` I found a `package.json` file there which had the version of `angular cli` as`8.3.3` the older one.

1. I deleted that. <<<<<< **this is the crucial step.**
2. Then I navigated to `C:\Users\ARPAN\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` deleted evrything inside the folder.
3. Ran `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
4. `npm cache clean --force`
5. `npm install -g @angular/cli`

**It worked as a charm! Here is the log!**

```
C:\Users\ARPAN>ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.0.1
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.1
@angular-devkit/core         10.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.1
@schematics/angular          10.0.1
@schematics/update           0.1000.1
rxjs                         6.5.5
```

Comment: if package.json is not found then package-lock.json and node_modules folder in C:\Users\ARPAN> should be deleted. anyway, thanks for the answer it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your old version was cached by npm.

Try Following steps:

**1- Remove your current version**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

**2-  Clean your cache**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**3- Then install the newest version**

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: pls see my question, i have edited and added a screenshot after following ur steps. it is still not working....

Comment: I treid doing the steps in admin mode, it shows the latest version in admin mode, buit in normal mode it still points to the older version

Comment: what about using npm cache verify ?

Comment: I tried that as well , pls see the logs in white color screenshot attached

Comment: can u pls suggest me what to do? I am still not able to update it. Pls help me

Comment: No, I had an extra `package.json` file in `C:\Users\ARPAN` which had the older version , I had to delete that, just manually clearing the cache did not help.

Comment: I have this issue with Angular 13: still showing me 10.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that `C:\Users\[my user name]\AppData\Roaming\npm` contained `angular\cli` subfolder - I've removed it manually (as well as all ng files in the folder). And then re-run ng installation. Finally the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the node version I had installed using nvm (v16)

Then I switched to the node version I had installed without using nvm (v14). After that, i re-run the installation commands

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli`

It's did works for me

Answer (score 0):

I did it too, after doing:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

I checked the angular version, still older version. What I did:
rerun the command with this:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

then everything was set up