# After installing angular 12 still it is showing 13 version

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

Mistakenly installed angular prelease version.
Now unable to uninstall the prelease version and install stable version.[image]

Comment: "@angular/core": "13.1.2" -> update package.json with the version you want, then delete package-lock.json and node_modules and run npm install

Comment: Want to install globally

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like you have installed angular 12 on specific project.

If you want to install the specific version of angular globally, you need to uninstall current version of angular (if you have already installed), then you can install angular version as per required.

To uninstall the current version of angular cli: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

To install specific version of angular globally: `npm install -g angular-cli@ANGULAR_VERSION`

Here **ANGULAR_VERSION** means angular version that you are going to install. Please replace ANGULAR_VERSION with angular version (e.g. 10/11/12/13).

In your case if you want to install angular 13 globally then you can use: `npm install -g angular-cli@13`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696731/ng-v-still-showing-older-version-number-after-updating-to-latest-angular-cli-ver. I found the similar issue as above link. I got my solution