# ng --version showing wrong angular version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

installed angular next version using
**ng update -g @angular/cli --next**. so it installed 13.2.0-next.1
now I tried to install angular stable version using

**npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm clean cache --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@13**

**ng --version** showing angular next version only
***@angular-devkit/architect 0.1302.0-next.1 @angular-devkit/core 13.2.0-next.1 @angular-devkit/schematics 13.2.0-next.1 @angular/cli 13.2.0-next.1 @schematics/angular 13.2.0-next.1***

Answer (score 0):

I had that kind of issue but the update commande didn't work i solved it by running theses commandes:

->npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

->npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Comment: tried, same error

Comment: when I run the command "" ng --version"" 
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1302.0-next.1
@angular-devkit/core         13.2.0-next.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.2.0-next.1
@schematics/angular          13.2.0-next.1

 but in  C:\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json
showing 13.1.2

Comment: do the same thing with @angular-devkit/architect and @angular-devkit/core while not pointing out any version but with the flag --legacy-peer-deps. Something uninstaling theses modules and reinstall them with this given flag above.

Comment: I found the issue. Issue was, two  package.json file were there. One  in c://user/ ravi & another in admin. So, after deleting my local package.json file. It working fine. Stack over Flow solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696731/ng-v-still-showing-older-version-number-after-updating-to-latest-angular-cli-ver

Comment: good to hear dear