# Why when I install Angular 17.1.0, the command ng --version show me Angular 16.2.0?

Tags: angular

[install Angular 17.1.0 but shows 16.2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3WEu.jpg)

Why when I install Angular 17.1.0 the command ng version show me Angular 16.2.0 ?

I am using nvm and the console is Windows PowerShell.

How do you resolve this error?

Thank you so much.

Comment: probably has to do with differences between global and local.  ("ng" will run global, unless in the current directory for your angular project?)  You might run the install without the "-g".  So when you do "ng version" at your project's directory it's showing the local version.  From outside it'll show global.

Comment: May be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696731/ng-v-still-showing-older-version-number-after-updating-to-latest-angular-cli-ver